# how to insert multi line equation in the tabular environment?

Tags: tables, equations, align, arrays, cases

How can insert multi line equation in the tabular environment?

For example see the following code that can show my request.

```
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
    &a &b\\
    &u=\begin{cases}  0;& i=0\\ 1;& i \neq 0  \end{cases} $e\\
    &c &d
\end{tabular}
```

Should I use another environment instead of the `tabular`?

@Grundlingh:

In fact, I'm trying to use the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
&(A) $\ds u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~&(B) $\ds u=\sqrt{x^4+y^4}$\\
&(C) $\ds u=\sqrt[3]{xy}$ &(D) $\ds u=\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}$\\
&(E) $\ds u=\sqrt[3]{x^4+y^4}$ &(F) u=\begin{cases}e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}; &x^2+y^2\neq 0\\ 0; &x^2+y^2=0\end{cases}\\
&(G) $\ds u=\sqrt[3]{x}\sin y$ &(H) $\ds u=\sqrt[3]{y}\tan x$\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Instead of using `tabular`, you could use `array`. Regardless, it is not 100% clear from your example code what you're aiming for.

Comment: I don't understand the first empty column; delete all starting `&` characters and use `\begin{tabular}{l@\hspace{5em}l}` which spares you from inserting all those `~`'s. You are also missing two `$` characters in the cell containing the `cases` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,varwidth,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\varwidth[c]{\linewidth}}l<{\endvarwidth}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}l<{$}}
\def\ds{\mathrm{d}s}%  don't know what your \ds should be ....
\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1.7}
\begin{tabular}{rMrL}
(A) & \ds u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &(B) & $\ds u=\sqrt{x^4+y^4}$\tabularnewline
(C) & \ds u=\sqrt[3]{xy}   &(D) & $\ds u=\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}$\tabularnewline
(E) & \ds u=\sqrt[3]{x^4+y^4} & (F) & 
  \[ u=\begin{cases}e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}; &x^2+y^2\neq 0\\ 0; &x^2+y^2=0\end{cases} \] \tabularnewline
(G) & \ds u=\sqrt[3]{x}\sin y & (H) & $\ds u=\sqrt[3]{y}\tan x$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution for this some time back using saveboxes. Use a savebox to hold the aligned content, then use the saveboxes in the tabular.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox\unistrain
\begin{lrbox}{\unistrain}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
      \epsilon_1 &= \frac{\sigma_1}{E} \\
      \epsilon_2 &= -\nu \epsilon_1 \\
      \epsilon_3 &= -\nu \epsilon_1
    \end{align*} 
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\newsavebox\unistress
\begin{lrbox}{\unistress}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
      \sigma_1 &= E \epsilon_1 \\
      \sigma_2 &= 0 \\
      \sigma_3 &= 0
    \end{align*} 
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{table}
  \label{tab:stress_strain_relations}
  \caption{Elastic Stress-Strain Relations}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
      Type of Stress & Principal Strains & Principal Stresses \\ \hline \hline
      Uniaxial & \usebox{\unistrain} & \usebox{\unistress} \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible we have equation numbers inside this table?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but does this work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    a &=b\\
    u &=\begin{cases}  0;& i=0\\ 1;& i \neq 0  \end{cases} &e\\
    c &=d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```