# I am trying to improve the aesthetics of an organic chemistry lab report

Tags: tables, graphics, letterhead

I have included a sample of a basic organic chemistry lab report. If you compile the code, you will see that the top descriptive text is not properly aligned with the university logo, and that the tables' lines are not perfectly trimmed. I would greatly appreciate if someone could please point me to some tips. Thank you very much for your time!

lab.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{achemso}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=10pt,aboveskip=10pt}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{changes}

%Load math package
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Make cell space and scientific notation
\usepackage{longtable, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}

%To generate scientific notation later-on
\providecommand{\sci}[1]{\protect\ensuremath{\times 10^{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{e}{}}}}


\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{Concordia_Logo2.png}
\hfill\mbox{Johnathan}\\
\hspace*{0pt}
\hfill{\underline{Student ID:} 123456}\\
\hspace*{0pt}
\hfill{Laboratory report}\\
\hspace*{0pt}

\centerline{\Large\textbf{Identification of a Petroleum Hydrocarbon}}

%Start writing text
\section{Results}
\subsection{Tables}

%Table 1
\begin{longtable}{ Cr *{6}{l}SS}
  \caption{Measurement of the unknown's boiling point(bp) and refractive index(RI)}\\
  \toprule
 & Substance & 1\textsuperscript{st} drop(\SI{}{\celsius}) & \sfrac{1}{2} Flask(\SI{}{\celsius}) & 1\SI{}{\ml} left(\SI{}{\celsius}) & RI (20.0\SI{}{\celsius})\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \caption*{The unknown substance's boiling point range is 67-70\SI{}{\celsius} at an atmospheric pressure of \textbf{insert atm here}. 
  The refractive index was measured at a temperature of 20.0\SI{}{\celsius}.}.
  \endlastfoot

  & 206 & 67 & 79 & 70 & 1.4249\\
\end{longtable}

%Table2
\begin{longtable}{ Cr *{6}{l}SS}
  \caption{Computation of the unknown substance's density(\rho)}\\
  \toprule
 & Substance & Mass_{1}(\SI{}{\gram}) & Mass_{2}(\SI{}{\gram}) & Mass_{3} (\SI{}{\gram}) & Mass_{Avg}(\SI{}{\gram}) & Density(\SI{}{\gram}\textbackslash\SI{}{\ml})\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule

  \caption*{The mass of three 1\SI{}{\ml} samples of the unknown hydrocarbon was measured separately to obtain an average mass (Mass\textsubscript{\textit{Avg}}). 
  The density was then obtained by dividing Mass\textsubscript{\textit{Avg}} by 1\SI{}{\ml}, which produced an identical value to Mass\textsubscript{\textit{Avg}}.}
  \endlastfoot

  & 206 & 5.42\sci{-1} & 5.39\sci{-1} & 5.50\sci{-1} & 5.44\sci{-1} &  5.44\sci{-1} \\
\end{longtable}

%Table 3
\begin{longtable}{ Cr *{5}{l}SS}
  \caption{Identification of the unknown substance}\\
  \toprule
  & & Substance & Bp(\SI{}{\celsius}) & Density(\rho}) & RI\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \caption*{Insert description here}.
  \endlastfoot

  & Unknown  & 206 & \fcolorbox{lightgray}{lightgray}{67-70}  & 5.44\sci{-1} & \fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{1.4249}\\
  \addlinespace
  & Reference  & Cyclopentane & 49  & 7.46\sci{-1} & 1.4065\\
  &   & Hexane & \fcolorbox{lightgray}{lightgray}{69}  & 6.59\sci{-1} & 1.3749\\
  &   & Cyclohexane & 81  & 7.79\sci{-1} & \fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{1.4266}\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Here is the logo:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use two centered (`[c]`) `minipage`s with different length (5cm and 10 cm) for the logo and the text side on side:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{Concordia_Logo2.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{10cm}
  \begin{flushright}
  Johnathan

%\hspace*{0pt}
  \underline{Student ID:} 123456

%\hspace*{0pt}
  Laboratory report
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

With environment `flushright` the text is right justified. See that I added a vertical space with `\vspace{3em}` to get a greater space between header and title line.

In your table you have empty columns that I deleted.  See for example table 1 with only 5 real columns:

```
\begin{longtable}{*{5}{l}}%Cr *{6}{l}SS
  \caption{Measurement of the unknown's boiling point (bp) and refractive index (RI)}\\
  \toprule
 Substance & 1\textsuperscript{st} drop(\SI{}{\celsius}) & $\sfrac{1}{2}$ Flask(\SI{}{\celsius}) & 1\SI{}{\ml} left(\SI{}{\celsius}) & RI (20.0\SI{}{\celsius})\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \caption*{The unknown substance's boiling point range is 67-70\SI{}{\celsius} at an atmospheric pressure of \textbf{insert atm here}. 
  The refractive index was measured at a temperature of 20.0\SI{}{\celsius}.}.
  \endlastfoot

 206 & 67 & 79 & 70 & 1.4249\\
\end{longtable}
```

See the deleted leading `&` in the line with the values and see the changed colimn definition (your original you find behind the comment sign).

There were several other warnings and errors I get rid of with commenting some called packages (see the complete MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=10pt,aboveskip=10pt}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{changes}

%Load math package
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Make cell space and scientific notation
\usepackage{longtable, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}

%To generate scientific notation later-on
\providecommand{\sci}[1]{\protect\ensuremath{\times 10^{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{e}{}}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{Concordia_Logo2.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{10cm}
  \begin{flushright}
  Johnathan

%\hspace*{0pt}
  \underline{Student ID:} 123456

%\hspace*{0pt}
  Laboratory report
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{3em}
\centerline{\Large\textbf{Identification of a Petroleum Hydrocarbon}}

%Start writing text
\section{Results}
\subsection{Tables}

%Table 1
\begin{longtable}{*{5}{l}}%Cr *{6}{l}SS
  \caption{Measurement of the unknown's boiling point (bp) and refractive index (RI)}\\
  \toprule
 Substance & 1\textsuperscript{st} drop(\SI{}{\celsius}) & $\sfrac{1}{2}$ Flask(\SI{}{\celsius}) & 1\SI{}{\ml} left(\SI{}{\celsius}) & RI (20.0\SI{}{\celsius})\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \caption*{The unknown substance's boiling point range is 67-70\SI{}{\celsius} at an atmospheric pressure of \textbf{insert atm here}. 
  The refractive index was measured at a temperature of 20.0\SI{}{\celsius}.}.
  \endlastfoot

 206 & 67 & 79 & 70 & 1.4249\\
\end{longtable}

%Table2
\begin{longtable}{*{6}{l}}
  \caption{Computation of the unknown substance's density ($\rho$)}\\
  \toprule
 Substance & Mass$_{1}$(\SI{}{\gram}) & Mass$_{2}$(\SI{}{\gram}) & Mass$_{3}$ (\SI{}{\gram}) & Mass$_{Avg}$(\SI{}{\gram}) & Density(\SI{}{\gram}\textbackslash\SI{}{\ml})\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule

  \caption*{The mass of three 1\SI{}{\ml} samples of the unknown hydrocarbon was measured separately to obtain an average mass (Mass\textsubscript{\textit{Avg}}). 
  The density was then obtained by dividing Mass\textsubscript{\textit{Avg}} by 1\SI{}{\ml}, which produced an identical value to Mass\textsubscript{\textit{Avg}}.}
  \endlastfoot

 206 & 5.42\sci{-1} & 5.39\sci{-1} & 5.50\sci{-1} & 5.44\sci{-1} &  5.44\sci{-1} \\
\end{longtable}

%Table 3
\begin{longtable}{*{5}{l}}
  \caption{Identification of the unknown substance}\\
  \toprule
 & Substance & Bp(\SI{}{\celsius}) & Density($\rho$) & RI\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \caption*{Insert description here}.
  \endlastfoot

 Unknown   & 206          & \fcolorbox{lightgray}{lightgray}{67-70}  & 5.44\sci{-1} & \fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{1.4249}\\
  \addlinespace
 Reference & Cyclopentane &                                      49  & 7.46\sci{-1} &                        1.4065\\
           & Hexane       & \fcolorbox{lightgray}{lightgray}{69}     & 6.59\sci{-1} &                        1.3749\\
           & Cyclohexane  &                                      81  & 7.79\sci{-1} & \fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{1.4266}\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I truly appreciate it! :D

Comment: I forgot to ask you: how could I reduce the white space between the tables to have a nicer fit? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into making your own document class, similar to what I did at [Template for Standard Operating Procedures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22591/3345). In the meantime, I think this fixes things. Your table problem appeared to be the result of extra empty columns. Change the alignment to something else if you like.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable, cellspace, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}


% Make a box for the student information
% From "how to insert multi line equation in the tabular environment?":
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24086
\newsavebox\header
\begin{lrbox}{\header}
\begin{minipage}{3.9in}
\hfill\mbox{Johnathan} \par
\hfill\mbox{\underline{Student ID:} 123456} \par
\hfill\mbox{Laboratory report}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{2in}p{3.9in}}
% From "Aligning image and text on top, with minipages":
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11631
\vspace{0pt} \includegraphics[width=2in]{\jobname} & \vspace{0pt} \usebox{\header}
\end{tabular}

\centerline{\Large\textbf{Identification of a Petroleum Hydrocarbon}}

\section{Results}
\subsection{Tables}

\begin{longtable}{*{6}{r}SS}
  \caption{Measurement of the unknown's boiling point(bp) and refractive index(RI)}\\
  \toprule
Substance & 1\textsuperscript{st} drop(\SI{}{\celsius}) & \sfrac{1}{2} Flask(\SI{}{\celsius}) & 1\SI{}{\ml} left(\SI{}{\celsius}) & RI (20.0\SI{}{\celsius})\\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \caption*{The unknown substance's boiling point range is 67-70\SI{}{\celsius} at an atmospheric pressure of \textbf{insert atm here}. 
  The refractive index was measured at a temperature of 20.0\SI{}{\celsius}.}
  \endlastfoot

206 & 67 & 79 & 70 & 1.4249\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```