# LaTeX Table problem

Tags: tables, tabularx

I would like to build a simple LaTeX table, something like a 3 columns x 4 rows table, as in figure (hand drew). The problem is that I cannot find anywhere a simple explanation about the code to insert to write things as I did by hand.

I mean, I know the tabular command, and all the codes to make a 3x4 table, but then I cannot find how to place text in multi lines and so on.

I would like something "big"!

[image]

Comment: You can use p-columns and use `\newline` inside a cell to get multiple lines

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you should use the `tabularx` environnement (need to use `\usepackage{tabularx}`). I only wrote one line of the table:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
$\Delta < 0$ & No real roots always holds true! & No real roots never satisfied!  And you can add text if you want to see a break somewhere\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 2):

An example with 3 columns, each `0.3\textwidth` (the last 0.1 text width can be used for the lines).

You get multiple lines with `\newline`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{p{0.3\textwidth}|}}\hline
a & b & c\\\hline
a & b1\newline b2 & c\\\hline
a & b & c\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Output result]

Remark: Normally you should avoid the lines around the cells, see for example https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

For the math, see also [how to insert multi line equation in the tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24077/how-to-insert-multi-line-equation-in-the-tabular-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Given that most of the cells in the table have a very organized structure, it's probably not a good idea to employ automatic line breaking to render the cells' contents. Instead, I'd use nested `tabular` environments. (In the code below, I wasn't too sure about the symbol that occurs in two of the three header cells...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}c<{$}|c|c|}
\hline
Ax^2+Bx+C & $\mathop{>}_1^{} \ge 0$ & $\mathop{>}_1^{} \le 0$ \\
\hline
\Delta<0 & 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \textsc{no real roots}\\
  always holds true!
\end{tabular} & 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
  \textsc{no real roots} \\
  \emph{never}  satisfied! \\
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\Delta = 0 &
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
  \textsc{2 coinc.\ solut.} \\
  $x_{1,2}\ge x_0$
\end{tabular} & 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
  \textsc{2 coinc.\ solut.} \\
  $x_{1,2}\le x_0$
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\Delta>0 & 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
  \textsc{2 dist.\ solutions}\\
  $x_1\ge x_{\max}$\\
  $x_2\le x_{\min}$ 
\end{tabular} & 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
  \textsc{2 dist.\ roots}\\
  $x_{\min}\le x \le x_{\max}$\\
  \null  % blank 3rd line
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thing taht the OP handwriting for second and third column meaning: $>, \;\ge 0$ and $<, \;\le 0$ ... :-).

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks, good one! Let's see if the OP weighs in with his/her thoughts... :-)